# How to list all defined environments in a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was wondering if there is a way to list all defined environments in a Rails application.

For instance if an application has 4 defined environments (production, staging, development, test) I would like to have obtain the following array

```
 ["production", "staging", "development", "test"]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you give a little context as to why you would want to do this? There might be alternative solutions for your problem..

Comment: @EmilKampp I just want to test that a yaml configuration files contains settings for each defined environment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get the list of defined environments through some Rails API. Environment files are loaded [dynamically based on the current environment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a05f3e5f96f7a8aa55483d91becdbe49b81833fd/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb#L55). So as already mentioned, you can just glob the `config/environments` directory for any `.rb` file.

```
Dir.glob("./config/environments/*.rb").map { |filename| File.basename(filename, ".rb") }
```

If you want to get a list of all `database` environments defined in `database.yml`, you can get the list from:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.to_h.keys
```

Assuming you are actually using AR.

Comment: Thanks @Jiri, your answer is the most complete answer until now !

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Env_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environments"
all_env = Dir.entries(Env_path) - ['.','..']
environments = []
all_env.each{|env| environments << env.gsub(".rb", '')} 
print environments
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 you can do the following as `Rails.root` returns a [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'environments', '*.rb')].map { |fname| File.basename(fname, '.*') }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
environments = Dir.entries(Rails.root.join("config","environments").to_s).grep(/\.rb$/).map { |fname| fname.chomp!(".rb") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan config/environments for .rb. As idea.